# Best strategy for turning off computer/laptop monitors to save energy but not reduce lifespan?

Tags: electricity, energy-use, energy-management, computing, electronics

When doing what's best for our planet, there are often trade-offs involved.  One such trade-off can be saving energy vs. reducing lifespan of equipment (which can result in significant environmental costs).

To save energy, is it best to have modern (manufactured after 2010) LED computer monitors automatically turn off every 2-3 minutes of computer/laptop non-use, or will that significantly shorten their lifespan?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/274194/lcd-lifespan-does-frequently-10-times-a-day-turning-on-off-lcd-shortens-its.

Answer (score 3):

Modern monitors use LED backlights. LEDs are not damaged by being turned on or off.

In short; I can't see any reason why this would do anything to the lifetime of the monitor, and it has never been a worry for me. Other parts typically wear out before the monitor for laptops.

Comment: Many are LCD...

Comment: @Barreto Backlight is led. That's the relevant thing here. There's no such thing as a LED monitor.

Comment: I see, I misread your answer